# WebGL content goes fuzzy after fullscreen

Tags: javascript, webgl, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, html5-fullscreen

I've got an HTML5 document containing an iframe sourcing WebGL content. I've marked the iframe for *allowfullscreen=true* and the WebGL content makes calls to the HTML5 fullscreen api. In Chrome and Firefox, the fullscreen request happens and works just fine. The WebGL content renders in the full window at highest resolution. In IE-11, however, the window gets full screened, but the webgl Content is now blurry beyond recognition. Is this a known flaw for IE-11? Is there something I have to do to fullscreen to make it work with IE-11 correctly?

Comment: Have you checked how your canvas gets resized? WebGL doesn't automatically change the resolution of a canvas. it's up to the your own JavaScript to do that. It's possible whatever JavaScript your using to do that is doing it wrong or doing it in a way incompatible with IE11. Put some `console.log` messages in and see what's happening

Comment: I'll try that out and see what I can find out.